# Which functions to override with a custom QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt, proxy, model, qt4.8

So I have a custom QAbstractItemModel that overrides the following functions:

```
QVariant data(..) const;
QVariant headerData(..) const;
QModelIndex index(..) const;
QModelIndex parent(..) const;
int rowCount(..) const;
int columnCount(..) const;
virtual bool removeRows(..);
```

Is it necessary to override all of these in a custom QSortFilterProxyModel that uses my model as a source?

The source of my confusion is this excerpt from the manual:

> Since QAbstractProxyModel and its subclasses are derived from
>   QAbstractItemModel, much of the same advice about subclassing normal
>   models also applies to proxy models. In addition, it is worth noting
>   that many of the default implementations of functions in this class
>   are written so that they call the equivalent functions in the relevant
>   source model. This simple proxying mechanism may need to be overridden
>   for source models with more complex behavior; for example, if the
>   source model provides a custom hasChildren() implementation, you
>   should also provide one in the proxy model.
>   https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#subclassing

Comment: No. `QSortFilterProxyModel` already overrides them. The only functions you need to override (it's even not required) are protected virtual ones, such as ` QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan()` etc.

Comment: That seems to go against what the qt manual says, hasChildren() isn't protected virtual?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the manual excerpt?  Also note that it's referring to `QAbstractProxyModel` and not `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Comment: I've updated the question with the link to the excerpt. It's on the page for the `QSortFilterProxyModel` as it's a subclass of `QAbstractProxyModel`

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to override these functions.

Simple example QSortFilterProxyModel usage below:

Model.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <QAbstractListModel>

class Model : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum Roles {
        Name = Qt::UserRole + 1
    };

    Model(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~Model();

    // QAbstractItemModel interface
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const noexcept override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const noexcept override;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const noexcept override;

private:
    QStringList list_;

};
```

Model.cpp

```
#include "Model.hpp"

Model::Model(QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel{parent}
{
    list_ << "Adam" << "John" << "Alice" << "Kate";
}

Model::~Model()
{

}

int Model::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const noexcept
{
    return list_.size();
}

QVariant Model::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const noexcept
{
    if(!index.isValid() || role < Name)
        return QVariant{};

    auto name = list_[index.row()];

    if(role == Name)
        return name;

    return QVariant{};
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> Model::roleNames() const noexcept
{
    return QHash<int, QByteArray>{{Name, "name"}};
}
```

FilterModel.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

class FilterModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FilterModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~FilterModel();

    Q_INVOKABLE void setFilterString(const QString& filter) noexcept;

};
```

FilterModel.cpp

```
#include "FilterModel.hpp"
#include "Model.hpp"

FilterModel::FilterModel(QObject *parent) : QSortFilterProxyModel{parent}
{

}

FilterModel::~FilterModel()
{

}

void FilterModel::setFilterString(const QString &filter) noexcept
{
    setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    setFilterFixedString(filter);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "Model.hpp"
#include "FilterModel.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Model model;
    FilterModel filterModel;

    filterModel.setSourceModel(&model);
    filterModel.setFilterRole(Model::Name);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQmlContext* ctx = engine.rootContext();
    ctx->setContextProperty("filterModel", &filterModel);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    width: 200
    height: 300

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        TextField {
            id: textField

            Layout.fillWidth: true

            placeholderText: "Search..."

            onTextChanged: { filterModel.setFilterString(textField.text) }
        }

        ListView {
            id: view

            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            clip: true

            model: filterModel

            delegate: Text {
                width: parent.width

                text: name

                font.pointSize: 14
                font.bold: true

                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice if you have a custom class as an item of model, you have to override

```
 bool QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
```

for your filter.